# How to choose last element from class using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to parse prices from

[image]

I want to take the maximum possible period. But when I use

[image]

`driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-group')[-1].click(`)

I get 15 years.

How I can fix it?

Can I additionally upload all these elements to the list and select the last one from them?

Comment: Not smart way, but maybe by text ? "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='btn btn-default btn-xs' and text()='30y']") "

Comment: I thought about it. It seems to me that the maximum term can be different, so I would choose the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to click on last element using xpath expression

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn-group"]//a')[-1].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to put some delay before the

```py
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-group')
```

command.
It seems that you are grabbing the elements before all of them are loaded properly.
So, I think

```py
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-group')[-1].click()
```

should work better

Comment: I checked it. I have the same result